# Existing name code (java)

Tags: java

I have problem with my school assignment (java code) i would like an warrning message with name that it is already exsits! everything is working fine but i just want to add a code in the brackets.

```
 public void add (Wapen index)
    {
        if (wapen.contains(index)){
            wapen.add(index);
            System.out.println(" message");

    }else {
        System.out.println("message ");

    }
}
```

Comment: does a SuperWapen have a name field?

Comment: private ArrayList<SuperWapen>Wapen;

Comment: Could you show us your SuperWapen code

Comment: He/She means weapon.

Comment: In the `SuperWapen` class, do you override `toString()` ? Also, use [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) instead of `contains`.

Comment: Did you read the `ArrayList` documentation and/or do a cursory Google search about how to get a value from an `ArrayList`?

Comment: I was going to say add a name variable to the SuperWapen class, but @Johnny Mopp has a better solution.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to use `indexOf` as you are passing an object as argument. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

you should also pass the name as parameter and then use this parameter where you want to display name.

Method signature should be like this.

```
public void addWapen (SuperWapen index, String name)
{ your code  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Override [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) and [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) in the `SuperWapen` class.

```
class SuperWapen {
    private String superwapenName;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return superwapenName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof SuperWapen) {
            return ((SuperWapen)o).superwapenName.equals(superwapenName);
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then just do:

```
public void addWapen (SuperWapen index)
    {
        if (!wapen.contains(index)){
            wapen.add(index);
            System.out.println(" Superwapen is registered for superhero");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Superhero has this superwapen with the name: " + index);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i forgot that i cannot change "contains" to "indexof" coz our study is on contains :(

Comment: how to send you all project?

Comment: ok now kind of is working but it shows this : name :SuperWapen@a00e04    and the name i typed is different

Comment: Did you override `toString`? If not, is there `name` member of `SuperWapen`? Something like `index.name`?

Comment: yes override to string        private String superWapenName;

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: ok sorry my misstake i thought by override u ment using "this."